# Can't use JSTL on a simple example

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, jstl

Here's my current situation:
I've created a Maven project from my shell, using this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=it.my.current.package.example -DartifactId=Example -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
mvn package
```

Then I opened Eclipse, imported the project as a Maven one. I added those dependencies to my 
`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I created a JSP and a Servlet.

My servlet just sets some variables and my JSP use them with some JSTL.

I've added on my JSP this tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and the code on my JSP is really simple:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

My Servlet it's doing this:

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setId(1); emp1.setName("Sam");emp1.setRole("Developer");
Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setId(2); emp2.setName("John");emp2.setRole("Manager");
empList.add(emp1);empList.add(emp2);
request.setAttribute("empList", empList);
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Employee is a simple Bean.

When I try to run this application, from my Servlet, it actually shows me this, on my JSP:

```
${emp.id}      ${emp.name}      ${emp.role}
```

And it's not showing the value that I set on my Servlet.

I'm totally new to JSTL, so I googled first for my issue. I tried adding `jstl-1.2.jar` on my `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory, but it didn't work.

What's the problem then?

EDIT: what are the configuration I need to do on my container and project to run JSTL? Isn't enough what I've made?

Comment: how about simply `<td>${emp.id}</td>`

Comment: @ScaryWombat the output is the same. It seems like tomcat can't recognize JSTL, isn't it?

Comment: see my answer for an update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it is not a problem with JSTL. This notation: `${emp.role}` is EL (Expression Language) and it is not working.

Don't you have `isELIgnored="true"` set somewere in the JSP file? Like this:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
```

Or maybe in `web.xml`:

```
<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
```

It should be `false` by default, but if you use servlet version older than 2.4 then the default is `true`, so in that case you would need to set it to `false` in `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

You have version `3.1` in dependencies, but in `web.xml` file `2.3` version is used. To use Servlet `3.1` try to change your `web.xml` into:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    rest of the TAGs
</web-app>
```

Also remove:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

(it's for `2.3` version)

Comment: I've tried adding your code to my `web.xml` file but it does not "compile". Is it because of what I use here? `<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >`

Comment: Looks like you use old servlet where EL is disabled by default, try to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` at the beginning of the JSP file.

Comment: But if you notice what dependencies I've added to my `pom.xml`, I'm using servlet version 3.1.0... I'll try it anyway.

Comment: Thank you mike, it worked. So what was wrong in the begining? have I used a wrong archetype when I first created my project? It's really weird to see this after I added the javax.servlet dependency with the newer version...

Comment: @abierto I think that you choose good `archetype`, but must declare servlet version you want to use in `web.xml` anyway.

Comment: the fact is that, when I modify the web.xml file, adding what you wrote, still nothing happens. I don't like to add that tag to every JSP, it seems like the <jsp-config> tag is not "read" properly...

Comment: @abierto just change `web.xml` to have `<web-app...` that I have posted. Without `<jsp-config>`. It should change servlet version to `3.1` where EL is turn on by default, so you won't need to activate it in every JSP file. Like here [create-web-application-project-with-maven-example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/create-web-application-project-with-maven-example/) where they sey `Moreover, we must change our web.xml file to use Servlet 3.0:` (you can change it to `3.1` with `<web-app>` I posted)

Comment: Thanks a million Mike, was struck for days due to isELIgnored. Did not know, it is default to true in servlet version older than 2.4. Once again, thanks. Perfectly working now for me