# Model.addAttribute does not work in my springmvc application

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and am using Spring Tool Suite to run my application. I have configured my controller as displayed below and i am trying to print random quotes on my jsp. But the value does not get printed when i use `${randomQuote}` in my jsp.

My Controller is

```
@Controller
public class MyDemoController {

    String[] quotes={"To be or not to be - Shakespeare","Beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder",
            "With great power comes great responsibility"};

    @RequestMapping(value="/getQuote",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRandomQuote(Model model)
    {

        int randomNumber=new Random().nextInt(quotes.length);
        String randomQuote=quotes[randomNumber];
        model.addAttribute("randomQuote",randomQuote);
        return "quote";
    }
    }
```

My servletConfig is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kimble.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The contents of my web.xml are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Demo App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyDemoApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/myServletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDemoApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

URL that I hit : http://localhost:8080/Kimble/getQuote.html

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Adding my jsp details

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Demo App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>The Quote is:</h2>
    <p>${randomQuote}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change your `web.xml` header to be at least a 2.5 servlet version.

Comment: More detailed duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676636/jstl-variables-are-not-shown-in-el .

Comment: Changed the web.xml header to the 2.5 servlet version. Didn't solve my problem :( . Will check out the link you shared.

Comment: Referred to this post which solved my issue  :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648545/cant-use-jstl-on-a-simple-example

Comment: Changing the header to the correct 2.5 version should fix it, you shouldn't need to explicitly enable EL then. If it doesn't work you didn't use the correct header.

Comment: This is my new header                                                                                <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">  I did not have to explicitly enable EL.